# System rvm is not working on direct call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I am using CentOS. Here is my output:

```
# which rvm
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
# rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset
# /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

As you can see if I am using just `rvm` everything is working. But `capistrano` using full path in commands like this

```
[46f28bd9] Command: cd /var/www/app/releases/20140718172057 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset do bundle install --binstubs /var/www/app/shared/bin --path /var/www/app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --verbose
```

So it just fails and all gems being installed on default ruby instead of `ruby-1.9.3-p392@gemset`

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Maybe try `/usr/bin/env rvm`?

Comment: Are you using login shell? https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal

Comment: @NickVeys `/usr/bin/env rvm` produces same output as `rvm` and `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`, but `/usr/bin/env rvm ruby-1.9.3-p392` gives me `RVM is not a function`. Only `rvm  ruby-1.9.3-p392` works as expected
@nsave yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumptions:

- you are using Capistrano v3
- have already included `require 'capistrano/rvm'` in your Capfile
- when you `cd` into your project directory you have something like `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` setting up RVM for you.

You might want to try something like this

```
within fetch(:current_path) do
    with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute :bundle, "install"
    end
end
```

The way Tasks work in v3 is different: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#tasks

> **tl;dr:** execute(:bundle, :install) and execute('bundle install') don't behave identically!